# using C++ template programming to extract the field types of an arbitrary structure

Tags: c++, templates, struct, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

If I define a struct with arbitrary data types like:

```
struct custom_type {
    int a;
    float b;
    char c; 
    float *d; // etc...
};
```

Is there a common pattern using template programming (C++) to extract the field types of this struct and map them to some type-specific code handler at compile time ?

Some context: I'm creating an api that allows for clients to define their own arbitrary custom types, and still allow those to integrate with the underlying system I have for managing and introspecting these types, doing automated memory management and other housekeeping.

The "wrapping" template or other mechanism will allow this integration *without the underlying system knowing anything about the header file that defines the custom type.* From the client's point of view, the code accesses the struct in the normal way, but the template allows generic handling of each field in the struct.

Thanks.

Comment: C++ does not have reflection. Your only viable alternative is to define type traits, and force the user to specialize them for each custom type.

Comment: you might use typeid function and then use template specialization for specific data type.

Comment: @macroland thanks -If I understand correctly the typeid would only get me the type of the custom struct, not info on its fields. I suppose I could make the client code generate field info and register that with the system dynamically, keyed to the type id. Still, generating that info automatically means introspecting field types. Also leaves the system vulnerable to deliberate or inadvertent changes to the registered field info..

Comment: maybe you could try std::any, which will be introduced in c++17, a tutorial can be find here :http://articles.emptycrate.com/2016/05/23/c++17s_std_any.html

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you describe is called [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29). The C++ language features which support this feature are very limited (yet). However, with some tricks it is possible to achieve some level of reflection.

One example is Boost.PFR (Precise and Flat Reflection) by Antony Polukhin. PFR is an official boost library since December 2020 (boost 1.75.0), but [according to its documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_pfr.html#boost_pfr.intro.out_of_the_box_functionality) it is a

> header only library that does not depend on Boost.

Here is [one example from the README](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_pfr.html#boost_pfr.intro):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "boost/pfr.hpp"

struct some_person {
    std::string name;
    unsigned birth_year;
};

int main() {
    some_person val{"Edgar Allan Poe", 1809};

    std::cout << boost::pfr::get<0>(val)                // No macro!
        << " was born in " << boost::pfr::get<1>(val);  // Works with any aggregate initializables!

    std::cout << boost::pfr::io(val);                   // Outputs: {"Edgar Allan Poe", 1809}
}
```

In the chapter on [Limitations and Configuration](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_pfr/limitations_and_configuration.html), the docs state that at least C++14 is required, but at least C++17 is recommended. One important requirement is that

> T must be aggregate initializable without empty base classes

Some underlying techniques are explained in a [recorded CppCon 2016 talk with the title "C++14 Reflections Without Macros, Markup nor External Tooling.."](https://youtu.be/abdeAew3gmQ).

Comment: But I can't _loop_ over the structure's field this way, can I? Not much good then -- if I have to enumerate the fields by number anyway, I may as well enumerate by name :(

Comment: @MikhailT.: Yes, you can iterate over the fields. You will have access to each field's type, index, and current value. See [`boost::pfr::for_each_field`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost/pfr/for_each_field.html). Note that you cannot access the field's name.